# How can i connect to salesforce api to pull data into Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We have Snowflake in our organization and currently we dont have an ETL tool.
I would like to pull data directly from Salesforce into Snowflake staging table manually for an analysis.

Would it be possible to do this with python or java code ?

many thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the simple-salesforce library for python.
https://pypi.org/project/simple-salesforce/

run the query, write out the results to a CSV, then load the CSV into snowflake.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Salesforce Data Loader** (provided by Salesforce) : a simple interface to export Salesforce data to a .csv file. It's a java-based tool.

Once exported you can `PUT` your flat file in a Snowflake Stage then use `COPY INTO` to load into your final table.

Documentation available [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.dataLoader.meta/dataLoader/data_loader.htm)